# How to export eclipse plugins as separate features and use the feature in other feature projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have three eclipse plugin projects.

Plugin-A
plugin-B 
Plugin-C

Plugin-a AND Plugin-B has been added as a dependency for Plugin-C. And i have a .product file in Plugin-C. When i export eclipse product from this product file, Plugin-A and Plugin-B are bundled inside my project.

I dont want this to happen. I need to have Plugin-A and Plugin-B as a separate features. And if i make any change in Pluin-A or Plugin-B, only that feature needs to be updated. There shouldnt be a need to generate the complete product.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to update parts independently of each other you have to specify these parts as features. **For each plug-in project** A, B and C you need a feature project: ***File > New > (Other...: Plug-in Development >) Feature Project*** (see [Eclipse help: *Feature Project*](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/project_wizards/new_feature_project.htm)).

In addition, you would certainly also want a update site project: ***File > New > Other...: Plug-in Development > Update Site Project*** (see [Eclipse help: *Update Site Project*](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/project_wizards/new_update_site_project.htm?)). Open the `site.xml` file, add the features via ***Add Feature...*** button, click ***Build All*** and copy the whole project as update site to a shared folder or upload it to a server.

Note, both plug-ins and features have their own versions. If you update a plug-in, you have to update also the version of the feature that contains the plug-in, add the new version to your update site, rebuild and publish the update site.

See also: [*Eclipse p2 updates for RCP applications - Tutorial*](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseP2Update/article.html)